# C# anyone see why this doesn't correctly select row in a datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

i have a datagridview and i would like the rowheader to correctly select that entire row.
Although i thought it should anyway, it does not. i have tried the following but with no luck, can you see something obvious? =P 
regards, Dave

```
    private void dataGridView2_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
    }
```

Comment: Did you set SelectionMode to FullRowSelect?

Comment: i only wish the full row to be selected upon clicking on the rowheader, within the datagridview i still wish cells to be selected individually/multi-selectable.

Comment: in this case you have to select each cell individually in a loop

Comment: Be careful, if you're selecting each cell individually in a loop. On a larger DataGridView it can be inefficient (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ha5xt0d9.aspx)

Comment: Selecting the row through a loop shall not allow the user to delete the row if desired.. there must be another way =P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the

```
DataGridView.MultiSelect=false;
```

and

```
DataGridView.SelectionMode = FullRowSelect;
```

You can read about the [MultiSelect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.multiselect.aspx) Property and [SelectionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionmode.aspx) Property in the MSDN library linked.

If you want the user to select multiple rows, then set `MultiSelect` to true.

```
 DataGridView.MultiSelect=true;
```

**EDIT**

And then you can call your event like this:

```
private void dataGridView2_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
}
```

To select individual cells within the data grid view and select the entire row on row header click, set the selection mode to RowHeaderSelect

```
DataGridView.SelectionMode = RowHeaderSelect;
```

The MSDN explanation for `RowHeaderSelect` is: *Clicking a cell selects it. Clicking a row header selects the entire row.*

Comment: I wish to be able to select cells individually within the datagridview, and only select the entire row when the rowheader is clicked..